# Contact form: struggling with send button width. Can anyone help me?

Tags: css

I'm working on a contact form and I'm having a hard time struggling with the send button width. I want it to have the same width as the entire form, but it's not working.

What am I missing?

Live: http://baskra.com/teste/teste.html

CSS:

```
#contact-area {
    width:  100%;
}

#contact-area input, #contact-area textarea {
    padding-left:33px;
    padding-right:33px;
    padding-top:25px;
    padding-bottom:25px;
    width: 420px;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: -2px;
    border: 3px solid #FFF;
    background:transparent;
    color:#FFF;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    color:    #FFF;
    opacity: 1;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
    color:    #FFF;
    opacity: 1;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
    color:    #FFF;
    opacity: 1;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
    color:    #FFF;
    opacity: 1;
}

#contact-area textarea {
    height: 180px;
}

#contact-area textarea:focus, #contact-area input:focus {
    border: 3px solid #FFF;
}

#contact-area input.submit-button {
    width: 420px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Add `box-sizing:border-box` to the elements in order to include their padding in their dimension calculations..

Comment: You're welcome - you might want to add in a `-moz` vendor prefix if you want it to be supported in [current versions of FF](http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing).

Comment: I suggest you read about it. Just adding a line of code - of changing your width to 88% aren't really answers - they are solutions, but with no quality explanation that could help people in the future. http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/   -and- http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/  - are good resources

Answer (score 0):

change your button width to 88%

http://baskra.com/teste/style.css
line : 497

```
area input.submit-button {
width: 88%;
float: left;
background: url("http://www.baskra.com/images/form-button-bg.png");
background-repeat: repeat;
color: #000;
}
```